# Wpf Listview not displaying data

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a Model as following.. I dont want to do anything like INotify etc because nothing changes in the view, I just want to display the names in the View. And in the view model Iam exposing model property because in mvvm View should bind to the view model only. But for some reason the names are not being displayed..Please help..

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class Model
    {
        private string _name;
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }

    }

    public class make
    {
        List<Model> mod = new List<Model>();
        public make()
        {
            mod.Add(new Model { name = "Sam" });
            mod.Add(new Model { name = "Pam" });
            mod.Add(new Model { name = "Jam" });
            mod.Add(new Model { name = "Cam" });
        }

        public List<Model> modlist()
        {
            return mod;
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Model> _obcollection;
        private Model _Model;
        public Model model
        {
            get
            {
                return _Model;
            }
            set
            {
                _Model = value;
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Convert();
        }



        public void Convert()
        {
            make m = new make();
            _obcollection = new ObservableCollection<Model>(m.modlist());
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Model> obcollection
        {
            get
            {
                return _obcollection;
            }
            set
            {
                _obcollection = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Xaml for Main Window.:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Name="lstdemo" ItemsSource="{Binding obcollection}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=model.name}" Header="Name" />
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

And finally MainWindow.cs

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
```

Comment: I believe that the context inside `GridViewColumn` is the current item (not the DataContext). So the binding should be `{Binding Path=name}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item is already bound to a model.
Instead of `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=model.name}"`use `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"`

Comment: Yea I know it works..But the thing is View cannot directly talk to the model..It can only talk to the view model..Look at this MSDN link below http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx The diagram clearly states that the view can only talk to viewmodel

Comment: You're indeed talking to the ViewModel. Your view's DataContext is bound to the viewmodel, and  your Listview is bound to an observablecollection which is a property of your ViewModel. ViewModels are wrappers that can have multiple properties and commands for your view to bind to. If you didn't use the MVVM pattern you would only be able to bind to one object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your xaml should be following:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="lstdemo" ItemsSource="{Binding obcollection}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}" Header="Name" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```